# AJAX function undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```js
function getCustomers(searchTerm) {
  var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType)
      XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "hw8a.php?qu=" + searchTerm, true);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange =
      function() {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
          XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
          alert();
          xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
          if (response.getElementsByTagName("ERROR").length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("interior").innerHTML = "<tr><td>ERROR</td></tr>";
          } else {
            addCustomerToTable(xmlDocument.documentElement);
          }
        }
      }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
  }
}
```

Here's my requesting function.  When I run it the function comes back undefined, called by a keyup event in a text box: `<input type="text" name="search" id="searchi" onkeyup="getCustomers(this.value)">`

The PHP function searches a big block of XML, and I tested that on its own and it returns XML data.

I've tried a few different versions of the function with and without the browser compatibility stuff, not quite sure what I missed.

Comment: I'm answering from my phone so I'm not so sure that's the error. Anyway, the first thing I noticed is that you are passing `this.value` into the function but it is currently not accepting any parameter. The first thing I'd suggest you to check is that parameter, then you could retry to send a request and see if you still get `undefined` as AJAX response.

Comment: Yeah I didn't catch that when I swapped the function out, but it's actually not the problem?